# Need to extract rectangle coordinates from a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r, extract

New R user. I'm trying to create an observation window for a point pattern in R using a shapefile imported from ArcGIS. I've imported the shapefile and it is recognized by R as a feature class type:polygon. I need the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax of the extent and that is all in order to specify these in creating the owin object. I can't seem to extract these values from the polygon. I know this is very basic but I can't put 2 and 2 together here.

Comment: object@bbox if its an sp* object

Answer (score 5):

You can create a rectangle with the boundary box of your polygon. I use `rgdal` package to make a reproducible example, but you could use only `raster` package with `shapefile()` function instead of `readOGR()`:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
ogrListLayers(dsn)
polygon <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="scot_BNG")
```

Creates an extent object using bbox and convert it to polygon:

```
e <- extent(polygon@bbox)

e <- as(e,"SpatialPolygons")
```

See the results:

```
plot(polygon)
plot(e, add= T)
```

[image: Rplot]

Comment: see my "answer" above-- your solution worked-- thanks !

Comment: You do not need to call the bbox slot, the extent function does this for you. It is as simple as: e <- as(raster::extent(polygon), "SpatialPolygons")